# Set attribute with an empty string

Tags: jquery, jquery-3

I'm trying to toggle the `required` attribute on fields using jQuery. On page load I add the `required` attribute to the relevant elements:

```
$("[data-required]").attr("required", "");
```

Then I have a toggle function that does a number of things, including toggling the `required` attribute:

```
if ($(childInput).attr('data-required')) {
  if (element.checked) {
    $(childInput).attr('required', '');
    $(childInput).rules('add', { required: true });
  }
  if (!element.checked) {
    $(childInput).attr('required', false);
    $(childInput).rules('remove');
  }
}
```

However, in both cases (on page load and on toggle), the `required` attribute is being set to `required="required"`. Am I using the incorrect syntax, or missing something here? I can't figure out why "required" would be inserted into the attribute value.

`.attr("required", true);` and `.attr("required", "true");` are resulting in the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm not entirely sure *why*, but this works:

```
$("[data-required]").prop("required", true);
```

The if statement in the toggle function:

```
if ($(childInput).attr('data-required')) {
  if (element.checked) {
    $(childInput).prop('required', true);
    $(childInput).rules('add', { required: true });
  }
  if (!element.checked) {
    $(childInput).attr('required', false);
    $(childInput).rules('remove');
  }
}
```